# How to solve the compile error in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

The directory structure as following:

```
- test/
-- deps/
--- librtmp/
---- rtmp.h
---- Android.mk -> librtmp.a
--- .../  #other deps
-- Android.mk   -> test.a
-- src/
--- flv_muxer.c
```

The flv_muxer.c code snippet:

```
#include "librtmp/rtmp.h"
```

The compile error:

```
$ ndk-build
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : test <= flv_muxer.c
In file included from /Users/workdir/testproject/test/src/flv_muxer.c:9:0:
/Users/workdir/testproject/test/src/flv_muxer.h:13:26: fatal error: librtmp/rtmp.h: No such file or directory
 #include "librtmp/rtmp.h"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: ***  Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the compile error by adding `LOCAL_CFLAGS` or `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` as following:

-- Android.mk   -> test.a

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/deps/
```

or

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=                     \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/deps/                 \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/deps/librtmp
```